# Problem Committing with Magit

Tags: magit, osx, ess

I'm a relatively new convert to emacs and a very new convert to Mac.  After installing Emacs using the ESS installer (Version 18.10.2).

When I attempt to state a file for commit I receive the following error.

```
GitError! There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/s2/mjvyfw3d13zd8swxf8ds92c40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.  [Type `$' for details]
```

Pressing `$` yields the following.

```
0 git … add -u -- inst/process.R
  1 git … commit --
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
error: There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/s2/mjvyfw3d13zd8swxf8ds92c40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

  0 git … add -u .
  1 git … commit --
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
error: There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/s2/mjvyfw3d13zd8swxf8ds92c40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

- My EMACS Version

```
GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109))
 of 2019-04-12
```

When run with `M-x toggle-on-debug-error` I don't seem to get any different output.

```
GitError! There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/s2/mjvyfw3d13zd8swxf8ds92c40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.  [Type `$' for details]

  1 git … commit --
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
Waiting for Emacs...
*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
error: There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --socket-name=/var/folders/s2/mjvyfw3d13zd8swxf8ds92c40000gn/T/emacs501/server'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

More information.  From the below advice I was able to determine that commenting out the below lines in my `emacs.d/init.el` file allows magit to work properly.

```
;; (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-r-style-hook)
;; (defun my-r-style-hook ()
;;   (when (string-match (file-name-extension buffer-file-name) "[r|R]$")
;;     (ess-set-style 'RStudio)))
```

Comment: Does `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` get you a backtrace for the `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` error?  If so, add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  I have it working now.  The problem was in my attempt at a hook to set ess-set-style to RStudio automatically.

Thanks to another stackoverflow topic I saw that there was a specific `ess-mode-hook` I should be using

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502540/make-emacs-ess-follow-r-style-guide

Modifying my `init.el` file with the following fixes my issue with magic.

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
           (lambda ()
             (ess-set-style 'RStudio)))
```

Thanks to everyone for their patience in helping me muddle through this.

Answer (score 0):

Some type error has occurred. Based on basically "when committing I get `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`" it is very hard to know where exactly that error occurred so without you helping us help you that's all we can say.

Except maybe adding general debugging advice. You should start by trying to reproduce the issue starting from `emacs -Q`. We provide a tool to make that easier, see https://magit.vc/manual/2.11.0/magit/Debugging-Tools.html.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I ran emacs using the -Q argument as you suggested and the commit worked fine.  So from that, I suppose the problem lies outside magic and its dependencies.

Comment: From the above advice on running emacs with the -Q argument I did some more investigating and determined that the issue is with something in my /emacs.d/init.el file.  I'll start narrowing it down via process of elimination